# Unable to add heroku-postgres addon

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

Attempting to add the `heroku-postgres` addon with the command `heroku addons:create heroku-postgres` produces this error:

```
 !    Could not communicate with vendor, please try again later
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your network connection is having issues -- that error message you're getting means you were unable to reach the Heroku API servers. Just try it again in a few minutes and you should be good to go.

Comment: My experience the other day to this exact question was that there was scheduled maintenance. After the maintenance was over, the installation was easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev`

Comment: This does not work because the app `heroku-postgresql:dev` does not exist.